# Remote working: Should I join Home PC to company domain?

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, remote-access

I work from home and my PC is one the company bought for me.  I connect to the company network with VPN (Shrewsoft VPN Connect if that matters).

A fellow coworker (one who also works from home) joined his PC to the company’s domain.  The primary reason for this is so he could reference company PCs by name without having to maintain them in his hosts file.

This sounds like a big plus to me so are there any disadvantages to doing this?
Or, for that matter, what other advantages could it have?

**Additional Notes**

- I have seen this work so whether it
  can be done is *not* the question.
- Our employer has not specifically 
  requested that we do this.
- I use my work PC for work so I’m not
  concerned about snooping eyes on the
  network.

Comment: I would nbot join your PC to the company domain...grawity is right on with how to fix this more easily.

Comment: @KCotreau I do appreciate @grawity answer as it directly applies to the specific "big plus" mentioned in my question.  However, why not join to the company's domain?  If I may be so bold, that was the _main answer_ I was seeking.

Comment: Mostly connection things...You will not always be VPN'ed in to your server, and your computer will be looking for connections that are not there, and that will cause performance issues. Assuming you are not connected, the first noticeable example will be when you log in...it won't find the domain controller so it will have to time out before it used the cached credentials. Second, if you keep mapped drives, they will try to reconnect. There are more too.

Answer (score 2):

"Reference by name" is standard DNS, you just need to use the entire `<host>.<domain>` name. If you want to have `.<domain>` appended automatically, go to network connection settings, look for "DNS Suffixes".