# Network Privacy - Domain

Tags: networking, vpn, domain

I work remotely from home on my own personal computer. The network administrator joined my computer to the companies domain. I was told to use VPN as well.

My question:

**When I am at home using my personal connection (Comcast), can anyone see the websites I visit? I am  not logged into the VPN.**

Apologies if this is a noob question. I honestly have no clue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Being part of a domain gives the company full administrative rights to your computer, which basically means they have the ability to **access all of your files and can see everything you are doing**.

Actually using this power would in most cases be a serious breach of ethics.

Comment: Yes, but I am not connected to the network. I am at home. Do they have access to the websites I've visited? I was told by a friend of mine that it does some DNS stuff in the background, but they have no visibility, unless I'm onsite or logged into the VPN.

Comment: Great. I basically have no privacy on my personal computer. I wonder how long they've been monitoring my internet usage. I can't even look a nude picture or I'll be busted. Talk about breach of privacy.

Comment: Is it illegal for them to do this?

Comment: This is basically my situation too. However, I am not logged into the VPN. I am only logging into Windows using my companies username and password. My computer is currently joined to the domain but not on the company internet. http://superuser.com/questions/302817/remote-working-should-i-join-home-pc-to-company-domain

Comment: Mostly repeating what David said, but Yes. If your computer is part of the domain then the domain admin will have admin rights on your computer. If they abuse those then the admin will get fired or even taken to court. (Though I guess that may depend per country. Over here (NL) it is a criminal act.). So yes, they can, and no, they are not allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer is joined to their domain then they can gain root access on your box. I would advise installing [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and run a VM machine to connect to their network.